# Format links text in the bibliography to be exactly like other links

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to use `biblatex` for the bibliography with a normal color that is used for links. However, I do not want the link to be clickable

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@misc{CIGREConnection2016,
    title = {{Connection of Wind Farms to Weak AC Networks}},
    howpublished = {CIGRE Brochure},
    year = {2016},
    month = {Dec},
    url = {https://e-cigre.org/publication/671-connection-of-wind-farms-to-weak-ac-networks},
    urldate = {2019-5-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[style=ieee,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{CIGREConnection2016}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you want the URL string in the typeset bibliography to be colored in `Blue1`, but you don't want it to be a hyperlink -- is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that I misunderstood the regulations of my school. They say "When you include a URL in a citation (such as citations for internet sources), make sure that the URL is not underlined or otherwise appear as a hyperlink." This is the opposite of what I asked, which is easy to deal with.

Comment: You may want to edit the title of your query to make it consonant with the follow-up comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment, you wrote that the objective is to

> make sure that the URL is not underlined or otherwise appear as a hyperlink

An easy way to achieve this objective is to set `urlcolor=black` in the `hypersetup` instruction, i.e., to change

```
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}
```

to

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=black}
```

If the typeset URL string must use the standard text font rather than a monospaced font, I suggest you also load the `xurl` package, followed by `\urlstyle={same}`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@misc{CIGREConnection2016,
    title = {{Connection of Wind Farms to Weak AC Networks}},
    howpublished = {CIGRE Brochure},
    year = {2016},
    month = {Dec},
    url = {https://e-cigre.org/publication/671-connection-of-wind-farms-to-weak-ac-networks},
    urldate = {2019-5-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=DodgerBlue3,urlcolor=black}

\usepackage[style=ieee,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{CIGREConnection2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you want the package to apply normal hyperlink preferences in the text and exclude only the bibliographies, use the command `\appto{\bibsetup}{\urlstyle{same} \hypersetup{urlcolor=black}}` instead of `\urlstyle={same}`. That way, the arguments will apply only to the bibliography while text in the body will stay unmodified

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@misc{CIGREConnection2016,
    title = {{Connection of Wind Farms to Weak AC Networks}},
    howpublished = {CIGRE Brochure},
    year = {2016},
    month = {Dec},
    url = {https://e-cigre.org/publication/671-connection-of-wind-farms-to-weak-ac-networks},
    urldate = {2019-5-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage[style=ieee,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\appto{\bibsetup}{\urlstyle{same} \hypersetup{urlcolor=black}}

\begin{document}

\url{https://e-cigre.org/publication/671-connection-of-wind-farms-to-weak-ac-networks} 

\cite{CIGREConnection2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot that URLs are typeset with mono-type fonts, which is what they have probably been referring to

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `\url` with `\nolinkurl` in the field macro:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{samplea.bib}
@misc{CIGREConnection2016,
    title = {{Connection of Wind Farms to Weak AC Networks}},
    howpublished = {CIGRE Brochure},
    year = {2016},
    month = {Dec},
    url = {https://e-cigre.org/publication/671-connection-of-wind-farms-to-weak-ac-networks},
    urldate = {2019-5-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[style=ieee,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{samplea.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space{\color{Blue1}\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\cite{CIGREConnection2016}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(some pdf viewers will nevertheless make it a hyperlink because they search the text for typical internet addresses and make everything clickable which looks like a link, e.g. has www, http...)